# configure ckan with multiple sites

Tags: ckan

I'm trying to accomplish the following architecture in CKAN
"back" server which will allow users to add and update datasets and also upload datasets . domain "back.data.XXX"
"front" server which will be read only site domain "front.data.XXX"
database server which will be access from both servers.

When configuring the data upload plugin , we need to put the site_url in the config file. When uploading file from the back server , the file url is saved to the DB (back.data.XXX/dataset/GUID). This is not good because it is also shown in the front server and the front user does not have access to the back server

Is this kind of architecture supported ?
Thanks
Arik

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the site_url in the back server to that to that of the front server to see what happens?